# Sitecore publishing service status not working

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9

I'm new to sitecore and have been trying to set up my 9.3 local instance and the 4.2.0 publishing service.
following company documentation regarding the publishing service ,i have tried these steps multiple times:

- Downloaded and extracted the publishing files
- Created the ISS site and added it to the hosts files
- Added the connection strings files
- Executed the schema upgrade command successfully
  when checking the /api/publishing/operations/status url, I only get an server error code with no useful info, nor a log file.
  If executed the publishing service runs properly on cmd, but it's not detected by sitecore cms when publishing.
  anyone got any ideas?, thanks

Comment: When I do it following this guide, it works every time. http://www.stephenpope.co.uk/publishing

Comment: already did, no luck

Comment: Have you installed the Publishing Service module package onto your Sitecore website and updated the setting "PublishingServiceUrlRoot"?

Comment: yes, i've checked and with the default url I can publish but there is an error, if i change it to the url to the service url the publish button becomes disabled, as the service is not detected